# ionic 4 firebase auth phone verify code validation another page

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I used firebase auth with phone it's working well and I received code on mobile but I've a problem now.

I need verification code validation in another page not in same login page.

My code:

```
        const appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
        return firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber( this.final_phone, appVerifier).then(async (confirmationResult) => {
          console.log(confirmationResult.confirm)
          let alert =   await this.alertCtrl.create({
            header: 'من فضلك ضع كود التحقق',
            inputs: [{ name: 'confirmationCode', placeholder: 'كود التحقق' }],
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'الغاء',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'secondary',
                handler: (blah) => {
                  console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
                }
              }, {
                text: 'تاكيد',
                handler: data => {
                  confirmationResult.confirm(data.confirmationCode)
                    .then(function (result) {
                      console.log(result.user);

                    }).catch(function (error) {

                    });
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        }).catch(

        );
```

Now it's showing the alert to put code to verify but I need go to another page and put code when I pass `confirmationResult` then it shows:

> confirmationResult.confirm not function

Comment: Why dont you pass the data via URL to next page?

Comment: to verify code if true or false

Comment: What i mean that , you can pass the Code via URL to next page.Since it is an Ionic app, the URL will be hidden